# Print Elements Of ArrayList in correct format

Tags: java, arraylist

The problem statement is

> Write a Java program to create a new array list, add some Fruits (String) and print out the collection.

My solution:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter number of elements to add");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        ArrayList<String> fruits=new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
            fruits.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(fruits);
    }
}
```

### The output with test input

```
Enter number of elements to add
4
Apple
Mango
Dragon Fruit
Pineapple
[, Apple, Mango, Dragon Fruit, Pineapple]
```

The correct output required should be

```
[Apple, Mango, Dragon Fruit, Pineapple]
```

without the first ","

### What I've tried

1. Using **next()** instead of **nextLine()**;

The output then is

```
[Apple, Mango, Dragon, Fruit, Pineapple]
```

Using next() leads to dragon and fruit being added separately.

2. Using String variable

```
//new string variable
String v;

//inside the for loop
v=sc.next()
// I've also tried this with nextLine()
```

The output is the same as above.

I've tried this both on the platform where I have to submit the code and on eclipse.

There are similar questions, but they deal with the logic and not the formatting.

If there is a solution to this please let me know, I will delete my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `nextInt()` it reads the integer, but does not read to the end of the line. So the next call to `nextLine()` then reads everything after the integer to the end of the line which gives you an empty string.

One easy way to fix this is to just add an extra call to `nextLine()` after reading the integer.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
System.out.println("Enter number of elements to add");

// Read number of elements
int n = scanner.nextInt();

// Read the rest of the line
scanner.nextLine();

ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>(n);
        
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fruits.add(scanner.nextLine());
}

System.out.println(fruits);
```

Or alternatively, read the line then parse the integer from it.

```java
int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

Comment: thank you! It worked. I was not aware that **nextInt()** does not read end of the line

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do. First I'd create a method called append. This is what it looks like:

```java
public static<T> T[] append(T[] array, T value) {
    T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
    result[result.length - 1] = value;
    return result;
}
```

To add an element to an array, you would do:
`array = append(array, element);`

Then, to output the array, you would do: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`

Comment: Your code works, but the question has a constraint of using only ArrayList